# Client denied by server configuration (Apache, ISPConfig 3)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am working on a hosting Ubuntu server for a job at University. I am quite new to this and I followed this tutorial:

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3

It was working good, I tried to put a test php file on /var/www directory and it worked perfectly, but after installing ISPConfig 3, I cannot access to any file. I am always getting 403 forbidden error.

In the error log there are messages like these:

```
[Wed Mar 26 20:15:02.185290 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 2995] [client 127.0.0.1:40245] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/
[Wed Mar 26 20:20:01.288804 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 2994] [client 127.0.0.1:40251] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/
[Wed Mar 26 20:20:35.272490 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 2997] [client 78.62.218.86:64487] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/
[Wed Mar 26 20:20:35.814397 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 2997] [client 78.62.218.86:64487] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/
```

Permissions:

[image: /var/www folder permission]
[image: /var/www permissions]

DocumentRoot (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default):

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

And Apache2.conf contains:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am using Apache/2.4.6 and Ubuntu Server 13.10

Comment: Could you solve this? If so, how?